# NEHotspotHelper issue trying to authenticate network on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have registered my app for using the `Network Extension` API and enabled the background mode following the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704292/nehotspothelper-networkextension-api-ios9-0). So, I am able to see the list of wifis on range when the user goes to the wifi settings, but I don't know why I am not able to set my custom sentence on the desired wifis and set the password.

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Try here", kNEHotspotHelperOptionDisplayName, nil];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp.ex", 0);  // dispatch_get_main_queue()

BOOL isAvailable = [NEHotspotHelper registerWithOptions:options queue:queue handler: ^(NEHotspotHelperCommand * cmd) {

    if(cmd.commandType == kNEHotspotHelperCommandTypeEvaluate || cmd.commandType == kNEHotspotHelperCommandTypeFilterScanList) {

        for (NEHotspotNetwork* network  in cmd.networkList) {

            if ([network.SSID isEqualToString:@"MySSID"]) {

                [network setConfidence:kNEHotspotHelperConfidenceHigh];
                [network setPassword:@"mypassword"];

                // This is required
                NEHotspotHelperResponse *response = [cmd createResponse:kNEHotspotHelperResultSuccess];
                [response setNetwork:network];
                [response deliver];

                NSLog(@"Confidence set to high for ssid: %@ (%@)\n\n", network.SSID, network.BSSID);
            }  
        }    
    }
}];
```

The SSID is matched, so the code is executed over the desired wifi and `Try here` should appear under `MySSID` on the wifi settings, and the password should be applied too, but none of both things are working.

Any idea about what's wrong on the code? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. Instead of creating a response when the ssid is found what I've done is to create an array and add the networks matching my ssid and then call `createResponse:` setting all the networks in my array:

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Try here", kNEHotspotHelperOptionDisplayName, nil];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp.ex", 0);

BOOL isAvailable = [NEHotspotHelper registerWithOptions:options queue:queue handler: ^(NEHotspotHelperCommand * cmd) {

    NSMutableArray *hotspotList = [NSMutableArray new];

    if(cmd.commandType == kNEHotspotHelperCommandTypeEvaluate || cmd.commandType == kNEHotspotHelperCommandTypeFilterScanList) {

        for (NEHotspotNetwork* network  in cmd.networkList) {

            if ([network.SSID isEqualToString:@"MySSID"]) {

                [network setConfidence:kNEHotspotHelperConfidenceHigh];
                [network setPassword:@"mypassword"];

                NSLog(@"Confidence set to high for ssid: %@ (%@)\n\n", network.SSID, network.BSSID);

                [hotspotList addObject:network];
            }  
        }

        NEHotspotHelperResponse *response = [cmd createResponse:kNEHotspotHelperResultSuccess];
        [response setNetworkList:hotspotList];
        [response deliver];
    }
}];
```

Now I can see "Try here" under the SSID name and I can join the network with no need for manually adding the password.

Comment: Reading this file will help you better understand the HotspotHelper: https://github.com/theos/sdks/blob/master/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/NetworkExtension.framework/Headers/NEHotspotHelper.h