# info.plist settings of NEHotspotHelper

Tags: ios, plist, networkextension

As per [Santosh's Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704292/nehotspothelper-networkextension-api-ios9-0), I need to add some new items in my **info.plist**. However, I don't know how to do it with the following guide.

- The application's Info.plist MUST include a UIBackgroundModes array  *   containing 'network-authentication'.
- The application MUST set 'com.apple.developer.networking.HotspotHelper'  *   as one of its entitlements. The value of the entitlement is a boolean  *   value true.

Can anyone suggest me how to configure my target's info.plist accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to email **networkextension@apple.com** and ask for that entitlement.  They should get back to you with a questionnaire, and it goes from there.

Comment: Does the questionnaire need any certification or proof? For example, it requests information of my company or need to pay for something?

Comment: I believe nope, you do not need to pay anything