# How connect to WPA2 enterprise wifi, NetworkExtension, NEHotspotHelper, iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, networkextension

Recently I start to work with network extension in Objective C for iOS develop.

I have already had entitlement provided for apple to use Network extension, so I can connect to wifi network using NEHotspotHelper with this links:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/46924#46924

[NEHotspotHelper NetworkExtension API iOS9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704292/nehotspothelper-networkextension-api-ios9-0)

[How to get Wifi SSID in iOS9 after CaptiveNetwork is deprecated and calls for Wifi name are already blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555640/how-to-get-wifi-ssid-in-ios9-after-captivenetwork-is-depracted-and-calls-for-wif)

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/31150#31150

Now I want to connect to wifi WPA2 enterprise network (this network needs "user name" and "password" to authenticate).

My question: is posible connect to WPA2 network using network extension or NEHotspotHelper?

If it is posible, could you help me with a example? please..

Thanks for your time.