# Get local network hostnames in iOS

Tags: ios, bonjour, nsnetservice

I would like to get All device name in entire local network. I just been searching over 2 days and haven't find a solution yet.

I can able to get Bonjour services with using NSNetServiceBrowser. What i am trying to do is same as Fing app ( in app store) does.

As screenshot below, I would like to get "My iPhone" iPhone name with iOS.

[image: Fing can fetch all device name entire local-network successfully]

Regards

Onder

Comment: Did my answer help you? Or you need something different?

Comment: Hi @ArtemStepanenko, Your answer should be correct but i haven't tried yet because of waiting entitlement access from apple. Whenever it's ready i will try and mark your answer or if not i will let you know. Thank you for your helping !

Comment: Cool, let me know!

Comment: I'm sorry for being annoying, but would be nice to see any response from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `NEHotspotHelper` is what you're looking for. Specifically a `class func supportedNetworkInterfaces() -> [Any]` method.

In order to make it work, you'll need to accomplish some additional steps. Please, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39189063/1090309) to get more information.

Also don't forget to add **NetworkExtension.framework** to your target.

Comment: sorry for late response, it worked. Now i am creating UI, I will post the screenshot over here. Cheers :)

Comment: That's great. I'm happy to know your problem is solved.

Comment: How to transfer file (Image, video, text etc) to this connected network